# Minecraft Teleportation

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm building a Minecraft map, which I have never done before, and want to teleport the player to the actual map with a command block. How do I do that? I have searched Arqade and cannot find a command that I understand.

Comment: Have you tried using /tp ?

Answer (score 1):

this is considered a simple command in Minecraft, but I think I can help you. To teleport a player, have them either step on a pressure plate, press a button, or switch a lever that is next to a command block with the command `/tp @p x y z` When I say `x y z` I mean the coordinates that  you want to teleport the player to. To get those coordinates, go to the location you want the player(s) to teleport to, and press the keys: `fn+f3` (function key and the f3 key.) On one of the rows of text in the upper left-center, there will be something like `x=46.33263 y=3643.532366 z=125.23146`. You do not need the decimals to teleport the player, so just remember the numbers `46,3643,125` or whatever your set of numbers may be. Simply replace the `x y z` that you put into the command block with these numbers, and Ta Da! (Also, if one or more of these numbers are negative, then the number put into the command block *ALSO* has to be a negative number.) Just in case you didn't know, to get a command block, you do `/give @p minecraft:command_block` 
Hope this Helps!
-A

Comment: this is quite messy though

Comment: seems simple enough, I can't think of a better way to do it.